# this function must be called on the uimanager queue

Tags: ios, react-native

on manual capture (like in lib docs) library fires error "this function must be called on the uimanager queue" and app crash.
https://github.com/Woonivers/react-native-document-scanner

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder:

```
node_modules/@woonivers/react-native-document-scanner/ios
```

Edit the file `RNPdfScannerManager.m`.
Change this line:

```
// - (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
// {
//     return dispatch_get_main_queue();
// }
```

Then rebuild the app.

Comment: Has anyone submitted this as a PR to the repo? I don't want to have to make this change each time I refresh node_modules or whatever